# UIView subview auto resizing

Tags: uiview, autoresize, autoresizingmask, nslayoutconstraint

I wrote a little UIView subclass to show a progress HUD. That HUD view works perfect but I faced a little problem in the last days.

In my application I'm presenting a UIViewController in a custom way. When the user selects a row in a tableView I'm creating an instance of my second viewController, move it to the current VC, set it's view's height to zero, add it as subview of the curren VC's view (at the position of the selected cell) and animate the height back to original.

The behaviour looks pretty cool and works great.

But when the second view is added as subview, I'm adding a HUD to this view. When the second view is resizing to the original height, the HUD sticks to the top of the view and is just a few pixels high:
[image]

I played around a bit with NSLayoutConstraints... But I didn't get it working until now...

Has someone a good idea on that one? Or does anybody know good and well explained resources on these constraints?

The HUD is actually a background view with the little window as subview. All other elements (the progress view, labels and so on) are subviews of the little window.

Comment: are you loading view from XIB? if yes that try unchecking auto layout subviews and setting all possible position view arrangements to Off. It can be done at place where you set frames for XIB.

Comment: Didn't do the trick, unfortunately…

Answer (score 0):

In terms of good resources, I definitely recommend WWDC2012's 3 videos: Introduction to Auto Layouts for OSX/iOS, Auto Layout by Example, and Best Practises for Mastering Auto Layout. These have some tips for looking at ambiguity in the layout and dealing with conflicts

Another great reference is Erica Sadun's iOS6 recipe book.

Re your problem. I'm assuming that you're not seeing an error message and you're laying out the progress HUD entirely in the XIB. If so, it sounds like you have two constraints that aren't behaving as you'd like from the xib - the height from the top of the superView and the height of the HUD

Firstly, create an outlet for the constraints to the .h file

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *HUDSuperViewToHUDConstraint;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *HUDHeight;
```

Next, in the method in which you open the new viewController with the HUD remove the constraints so that there is no conflict when you first show the new view

```
[HUDSuperView removeConstraint:self.HUDSuperViewToHUDViewConstraint];
[HUDSuperView removeConstraint:self.HUDHeight];
```

After you've called [HUDSuperView layoutIfNeeded] for the first time, in the animation or wherever, add the constraints and call layoutIfNeeded again

```
[HUDSuperView addConstraint:self.HUDSuperViewToHUDViewConstraint];
[HUDSuperView addConstraint:self.HUDHeight];
[HUDSuperView layoutIfNeeded];
```

If you call these within an animateWithDuration it may even animate the appearance...cheesey

Hope this helps - it's probably more of a step toward the solution rather than the solution itself. Recommend minutes 17 and 53 in the AutoLayout by Example video too.

Steve

Comment: No. I'm creating the HUD entirely programmatically. And I'm getting a lot of errors on the log…
Seems like I'll have to learn how to use these Layout constraints. To me the concept is quite obscure and not easy to use. I didn't even get one simple test app done with it :) Thanks for the tip. I gonny try the WWDC videos.

Comment: If you're doing this programmatically, I'm better with that. I struggle with IB. Recommend setting the height constraint for the HUD i.e. @"V:|[HUDView(40)]" as either the last thing you do after you've laid everything else out in the new view controller or immediately after the view controller view is instructed to appear (animated?) then use layoutIfNeeded on the view that the HUDView belongs to. Good luck